# Fibers of the secant map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset CP^N$ be a homogeneous (or perhaps just smooth) complex
subvariety  and let $S^r(X)$ denote its abstract $r$-th secant variety
(the incidence variety in $X\times \cdots \times X\times CP^N$), and assume the
map to the actual secant variety in $CP^N$ (the projection
onto the last factor)  is generically finite to one.
 Is it possible that there is some point in the actual
secant variety whose fiber has a component that is
an isolated point and another component that is
positive dimensional?
  (I just care about the case where $X$ is
a triple Segre product if that makes any difference.)